# Assign the json value to label

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

here i have some json code.with 2 dict of data.like

```
name1
name2
lap1
lap2
```

Only label1,label2 are showing value. Label3,label4 are not showing the value !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake! That You have 2 dictionaries in jsonArray

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];

 NSDictionary *dict2 = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:1];

NSLog(@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"people1"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"total1"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[dict2 valueForKey:@"people2"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[dict2 valueForKey:@"total2"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
NSArray *jsonObject;
jsonObject = @[@{@"Id1":@"mad",
                 @"people2":@"12",@"total2":@"20"},
               @{@"Id2":@"normal",
                 @"people3":@"13",@"total3":@"30"}];


NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonObject options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

NSLog(@" JSON DATA \n  %@",arr);


for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {

    NSArray *keys = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] allKeys];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:0]]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:1]]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:2]]);
    //assign your label here line yourLabel.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

Note : It will work for dictionary having 3 keys

Comment: i tried like this `for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {
        
       NSArray *keys = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] allKeys];

        
        label1.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:0]];
        label2.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:1]];

        label3.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:2]];

        label4.text = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:[keys objectAtIndex:3]];

}` but it getting crash error : `reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'`

Comment: B'coz there is only 3 keys in dictionary that is 0 to 2, but you are using [keys objectAtIndex:3]; that goes beyond it's index !!

Answer (score 2):

NSData 'jsonData' is not traversable, but you can traverse jsonObject i.e NSArray containing dictionary objects.

```
label1.text = [jsonObject[0] objectForKey:@"people1"];
label2.text = [jsonObject[0] objectForKey:@"total1"];
label3.text = [jsonObject[1] objectForKey:@"people2"];
label4.text = [jsonObject[1] objectForKey:@"total2"];
```

Comment: Please use objectForKey, not valueForKey. valueForKey is a high level function that will take ages to return either what you wanted, or something very sophisticated yet totally unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
label1.text = [[jsonObject objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"people2"];
label2.text = [[jsonObject objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"total2"];
label3.text = [[jsonObject objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"people3"];
label4.text = [[jsonObject objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"total3"];
```

Comment: no when i use your code no value are shows in my screen ( label ). see my updated post. i have tried and it work for `label1,label2.`not working for `label3,label4`